# Get variable and count from 0

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

Forgive me if this sounds a little confusing ... I am trying to adjust the value of a progress bar based on my randomize variable.

```
var randomize = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 2000) + 1000);
```

How do I then get javascript to count from 0 to 'randomize' in seconds, so that I can apply it to my progress bar?

Comment: You can use the `setInterval` method and call a function that increases the value of the progress bar on each call. and while I'm here, your statement is really unnecessarily complex.. `var randomize = (Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) + 1000;`

Comment: @bblincoe it would be too fast for him to loop from 0 to randomized number. And in any case it wouldn't be a good solution because a for loop would block the execution thread, no other operation could be done meanwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var randomize = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 2000) + 1000);
var counter = 0;

var timer = setInterval( function(){
  if ( counter <= randomize ){
    // update progress bar
    counter += 1;
  }else{
    clearInterval( timer );
  }
}, 1000 );
```

Basically what I'm doing here is setting up a function to be called every second ( 1000 = 1 second in JavaScript). The timer will check if the counter variable has reached the value of randomize and if not, it will increment it's value by one.

Once counter is equal to randomize, the timer will be cleared.

References -

- [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)
- [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

Comment: I think that should be if (counter < randomize)

Comment: @pal - thanks for that :) I've chosen to use `<=` to include the last iteration.

Comment: When using $('.loadingprogress').val(timer); the progressbar moves to about 10% then stops .. why is this?

Comment: OK, when I use counter, the progress bar does not move, and console is showing 0 over and over.

Comment: I'm not sure what your progress bar control is, but the code listed above seems to work fine. Look here - http://jsfiddle.net/6sYhK/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var seconds = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
        seconds = seconds + 1;
        if (seconds == randomize) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: You scratch my back... I scratch your's!